# Making a GridView footer data bound like a Row data

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, footer

I have an ASP.NET project created with C# that uses GridViews.  The footer row contains a ratio of a total based on the column data over a set value from the data saying how many there should be.  The user needs to be able to modify the second value and have the footer update.  I am not able to find out how to do this or even if it is possible.  I contemplated using another GridView underneath, but ensuring the column lines sync between the two is a nightmare.  Any ideas?

Also, when I change the column data (using Edit/Update rows), the total is not updated when I click on Update, but does when I click on Edit again.  Can anyone tell me why this is and how to update the total in the footer on Updating?

Comment: You have to show us some code!

Comment: Can you post your client-side code for the GridView and your server-side code for the OnEdit and OnUpdate events, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you find that your edited fields are refreshed "one click behind" typically it's due to thinking you've rebound your `GridView` but actually haven't or you've rebound before making the Update.

With Gridview, a typical scenario whenever you place fields in a footer is to calculate it's values during databinding operations of the Page Lifecycle

It goes like this, your .aspx file defines some footer fields, typically some `BoundField` that has been converted to `TemplateField`s.  Here's a snippet:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" ...>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Field1" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field2") %>' ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="FooterLabel1" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

GridView Events in the code behind:  This is generally what you need to do to populate footer fields based on changing Row Values.  This is VB but you should be able to convert it easily enough.

```
// Create a variable at the Page level that will exist for 
// the duration of the Page LifeCycle
Private FooterLabel1SubTotal as Double

// Initialize
Private Sub GridView1_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBinding
  FooterLabel1SubTotal = 0.0
End Sub

// Accumulate
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataRow Then
    Dim Field2 as Label = e.Row.FindControl("Field2")
    FooterLabel1SubTotal += Convert.ToDouble(Field2.Text)
  End If
End Sub

// Populate Footer with formated value
Private Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
  FooterLabel1 = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("FooterLabel1")
  FooterLabel1.Text = String.Format("{0:F2}", FooterLabel1SubTotal)

End Sub
```

Now if you use any of the Built in Editing features of the GridView, that will cause a Postback and will cause the `GridView` to rebind, which should recalculate the footer fields each time.